How to insert into a Model as Soon as a View is created
I have an Exercise Model that has can belong to a Workout or it can be standalone:
@Model
class Exercise {
    var id: UUID
    var exerciseName: ExerciseName
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var sets: [Set]?    //When an Exercise gets Deleted all Sets associated need to get deleted
    var date: Date
    var workout: Workout?       //it can belong to a work but it doesnt have to
    
    init(id: UUID, exerciseName: ExerciseName, date: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.exerciseName = exerciseName
        self.date = date
    }
    
    
}

and then I have a Workout which should be initialized as soon as the user Navigates to AddWorkoutView so that it can be passed to the ExerciseView:
@Model
class Workout {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String?
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) //when deleting a workout you delete all exericses that happened during that workout
    var exercises: [Exercise]?
    
    var date: Date
    
    init(id: UUID, date: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.date = date
    }
}

How do I initialize a Workout when the users navigates to this page so that I can pass said workout to the sheet?
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct AddWorkoutView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var exercises: [Exercise]
    @State private var workoutName: String = ""
    @State private var showExercieSheet = false
    //var workout: Workout
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack() {
            VStack(spacing: 60) {
                VStack {
                    HStack{
                        Text("Create New Workout")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.leading)
                    
                    TextField("Enter workout name",text: $workoutName)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .padding()
                }
                
                
                if(exercises.isEmpty) {
                    //chat why does this VStack have padding that i didnt add
                    VStack(alignment: .leading ,spacing: 10){
                        Text("Exercises")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                        
                        Text("Press Add Exercise to create your first exercise")
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    List(exercises) { exercise in
                        Text(exercise.exerciseName.name)
                    }
                    
                }
                
                
                Button {
                    showExercieSheet = true
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Exercise")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .frame(height: 55)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                        .shadow(radius: 2)
                        .padding()
                }
                
                
                Spacer()
                
                
                
                
                
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    //Save the Content
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .underline()
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .padding()
                    
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showExercieSheet) {
                AddExerciseView()
                    .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
}

this is the view that the sheet presents:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct AddExerciseView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var exercisesNames: [ExerciseName]
    @State private var showNameInput = false
    @State private var exerciseName = ""
    @State private var selection: ExerciseName?
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
  //  private var workout: Workout

    
    var body: some View {
       

        VStack {
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    //more to come
                    showNameInput.toggle()
                    
                } label: {
                    showNameInput ?
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                        .resizable()
                           .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    :
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .resizable()
                           .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    
                }
                .padding(28)
              
            }
            if(showNameInput == true) {
                HStack{
                    TextField("Enter Exercise Name", text: $exerciseName)
                        .frame(height: 35)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .padding(.leading)
                    
                    Button {
                        //database operation adding exerciseName to ExerciseName model
                        if (!exerciseName.isEmpty) {
                            let newExeriseName = ExerciseName(name: exerciseName)
                            modelContext.insert(newExeriseName)
                            showNameInput.toggle()
                        }
                        
                    }label: {
                        Text("Add")
                    }
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .frame(height: 35)
                    .frame(width: 70)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
                    .shadow(radius: 1)
                    .padding()
                }
               
            }
         
            List(exercisesNames,id: \.self, selection: $selection)  { exercisename in
                Text(exercisename.name)
            }
            
            
            Button {
                //check If selection isnt empty than create an Exercise with this(selection) as the ExerciseName
                //and dismiss this sheet
                if(selection != nil) {
                    let newExercise = Exercise(id: UUID(),exerciseName: selection!, date: Date.now)
                    modelContext.insert(newExercise)
                    print("inserted: \(newExercise.exerciseName.name)")
                    dismiss()
                }
                
            } label: {
                Text("Done")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .frame(height: 55)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                    .shadow(radius: 2)
                    .padding()
            }
            
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            if exercisesNames.isEmpty {
                showNameInput=true
            }
        }
        
        
    }
       
}

#Preview {
    AddExerciseView()
}

So far I have tried creating a Workout object and inserting it into the modelContext inside an OnAppear modifier but it was not successful.

In the AddWorkoutView you have no code for the save button, maybe you should solve that first

The save button is just for saving changes made to the workout, the workout still needs a Workout object to work with as soon as this view is active

I think you wrote workout one time to many:) but if you create a workout with the save button then that is the object you want to pass to the sheet view isn’t it?

No I want the workout already created on this page than I add items to it and when the user is all done they can click save, but I need a workout to work with from the very beginning of the view

That's the wrong way around. In SwiftUI views are a function of state which means make the new workout first in a state and then generate the views for it.
onAppear is for external actions, not for state.
Eg use a button to init the workout and set it on a selection state, then use List(selection:).

Hii Malhal thank you for the answer, what do you mean by external actions can you give me an example?

Maybe like writing to file

if I make the workout a state I can't take advantage of SwiftData relationships like inverse and trying to call modelContext.insert anywhere except a button causes errors, is there truly no way to insert a workout in before the view is render or when it is rendered?

Make the state the selection. Use the button to init the workout and set it to the selection. Then use List(selection: $selection)

You can define an optional workout holder in the parent:
@State var workoutToAdd: Workout?

Then you can fill or nil it conditionally, for example when you are toggling the sheet currently:
Button {
   // showExercieSheet = true //  get rid of this
   self.workoutToAdd = .init(\* Custom Initial Data *\)
}

Then you can manage your sheet based on the existence of the workoutToAdd:
.sheet(item: $workoutToAdd) { workout in //  You are sure that you have an upcoming workout to add here
    AddExerciseView() //  You can even pass the workout as an argument to this view
        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
}

Then you can add workoutToAdd to the modelContext
wherever you need or just set it to nil to dismiss the sheet like nothing ever happen :)

This I what I tried but the @State property is not what  I want I want to have a workout created and inserted so I can pass it to the child view to edit it and take full advantage of SwiftUI relationships, so far I have tried insert it into modelContext inside a NavigationLink but that isn't working

how do I add workoutToAdd as soon as the view is created?

Following the answer: AddExerciseView(workout: $workoutToAdd)
